# would you mind waiting till or that

Tags: syntax

Shall I write

Would you mind waiting till both records are out before sending them to me    or

Would you mind waiting that both  records are out before sending them to me

Comment: You know [ask] . Remember to provide your thoughts on why this choice of words is confusing for you.  "Till" and "That" are rather different in meaning, so why do you think either one is possible here?

Answer (score 2):

*Wait* is not transitive in English, so *wait that XXXX* does not make sense.

*Wait for* is the normal collocation, so you could say *wait for the records to be out*. (*Wait for* can take a "to-" infinitive clause, but not an *-ing* clause).

But *wait till the records are out* is fine too: the *till* clause is adverbial, expressing a limitation

I don't see any practical difference in meaning, or reason to choose one rather than the other.

Comment: I'd use 'until' rather than 'till' in formal writing.